# UITableViewCells not displaying first time

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create an autocompleter using iOS 8, Swift and Xcode 6.3

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve, but I gave up... I hope someone can help here. The problem is that (custom) `UITableViewCell`'s are not displaying when the initial `dataSource` is empty. When adding data to `datasource` and reloading the `tableView`, the cells SHOULD display, but they don't... At least, the first time they don't... A second time, they DO... When I initialize the table with non-empty data, the problem doesn't occur.  I guess something goes wrong with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. In beginning, no reusable cells are found, or something. But I don't know why...

Relevant code, in ViewController.swift:

```
// filteredWords is a [String] with zero or more items

@IBAction func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = sender.text.isEmpty
    filteredWords = dataManager.getFilteredWords(sender.text)
    refreshUI()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! AutocompleteTableViewCell
    cell.title.text = filteredWords[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredWords.count
}

func refreshUI() {
    self.autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I created a sample project on github:

https://github.com/dirkpostma/swift-autocomplete

And a movie on YoutTube to show what goes wrong:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByMsy4AaHYI

Can anyone look at it and spot the bug...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of posting a link to your project, narrow down the issue to specific bit of code and paste the code into your question. Explain what is going on and what should be happening.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I added the relevant code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've accidentally hidden your cell.

1. Open Main.storyboard
2. Select Cell
3. Uncheck **Hidden**

Side note: As for why it's displaying the second time around with the cell hidden? It appears to be a bug. It should still be hidden (print cell.hidden, notice it's always true despite showing the text on the screen).

Comment: Excellent find! But now I'm curious as to why the cells will be visible again the second time they're used.

Comment: Wow, how did you find this? David aka Debug King? Thank you!

Comment: Now that I look at it again it's not really being reset (hidden == true, even when the text is displayed). Might submit a radar, with the sample project, to have Apple look into it. In the meantime not hiding the cell will work.

Comment: This solved my problem. I have the whole UITableView hidden and I make it visible when the user types something. But when I made the tableview hidden, also the UITableViewCell inside were set hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your code. Check out below code. It is because if you remember in Objective C you needed to check if the `Cell` was nil and then initialise it. The reuse identifier is usually reusing an already created cell, but on the first launch this does not work because there is no Cell to use. Your current code assumes always that the cell is created (re-used) because you are using ! in the declaration, so if you use the optional (?) it can be null and you then can create the cell

```
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? AutocompleteTableViewCell

    if cell == nil 
    {
        //You should replace this with your initialisation of custom cell
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL") 

    }

    cell.title.text = filteredWords[indexPath.row]
    return cell
```